# when am running IBMMQ am getting this error?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

**AMQ6235E: Directory 'H:' missing.**

```
Error:
  name: 'MQError',
  message:
   'CONNX: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN [2009]',
  mqcc: 2,
  mqccstr: 'MQCC_FAILED',
  mqrc: 2009,
  mqrcstr: 'MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN',
  version: '0.9.10',
  verb: 'CONNX' 
}
```

am unable to find solution for this problem,it is connecting to queue its showing this error.I cant expose code which i have run,but I can explain what that node script will do that first try to connect queue manager,then try  with the channel
name,host name,port name ,here problem is arises when it need to establish connection instead of that am getting this above error

Comment: Please could you update your question with a little more information. For example, the exact command you were running when you saw this error. Also, could you please issue the `dspmqver` command and paste the output into your question as well. Are there any messages in the `AMQERR01.LOG` at the time you see this problem? You should show us those too. Thanks

Comment: What is the significance of `Directory 'H:'`?

Comment: Please could you read my earlier comment, and update your question with the details requested, or at the very least describe your environment so we have any hope of helping you. Clearly we cannot know what the issue with your H: drive is if we don't know how you configured your system to use that drive, and we can't know why it is now not available. But we might be able to explain the reason MQ is looking for it if we could understand how you originally installed MQ, which is why I asked for `dspmqver`.

Answer (score 0):

this above problem arises because that particular network  drive is missing from the system's device and drive,for that either we need to map that particular network drive by click my computer and choose map network drive or we need to change the environment path that has been set for the directory creation in ibbmq postinstall.js  to some other drive which is present in the my computer.

Comment: So was MQ installed on this drive or what?